# Windows 7 GUI reference

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, windows-7

I maintain a large C++ application using Win32 and i want to use some of the new controls introduced in Vista/Windows 7 (New ballon help, command links, status bar notofications.

I have downloaded the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx), but i dont find a corresponding API Reference. I know that some of these controls will be not available from core Win32 - so i am looking as well for some source about which controls need which API (WPF or whatever).

Any Links?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 7 SDK site has a number of downloads and guidance pages which should help point you in the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx

The taskbar/notification API is further documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following Wolfs link and browsing for quite a while, i came up with the following entry point (on microsoft.com), that looks quite valuable to me:

[Windows User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663298%28VS.85%29.aspx)

and more specifically:

[Windows Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773173%28VS.85%29.aspx)

As far as i can see there is nothing that can NOT be done using core Win32.